# Inherit POS Javascript function in Odoo 10

Tags: javascript, inheritance, odoo, odoo-10

I am trying to inherit and modify the existing js function of `point_of_sale` module.
This is the function i need to inherit

**models.js**

```
exports.Orderline = Backbone.Model.extend({
set_quantity: function(quantity){
    console.log('quantity',quantity);
    this.order.assert_editable();
    if(quantity === 'remove'){
        this.order.remove_orderline(this);
        return;
    }else{
        var quant = parseFloat(quantity) || 0;
        var unit = this.get_unit();
        if(unit){
            if (unit.rounding) {
                this.quantity    = round_pr(quant, unit.rounding);
                var decimals = this.pos.dp['Product Unit of Measure'];
                this.quantityStr = formats.format_value(round_di(this.quantity, decimals), { type: 'float', digits: [69, decimals]});
            } else {
                this.quantity    = round_pr(quant, 1);
                this.quantityStr = this.quantity.toFixed(0);
            }
        }else{
            this.quantity    = quant;
            this.quantityStr = '' + this.quantity;
        }
    }
    this.trigger('change',this);
},
});
```

Here is my code:

**pos_model.js**

```
odoo.define('point_of_sale.models_inherit', function (require) {
"use strict";

   var module = require('point_of_sale.models');
   module.include({

   set_quantity: function(quantity){
       console.log('initialize');
             }


     }); 

 });
```

Now i am getting an error in console like,

```
 `module.include is not a function`
```

How can i inherit this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with below code snippet!! Already tested in `Odoo v10.0`

```
odoo.define('point_of_sale.models', function (require) {
"use strict";

var models = require('point_of_sale.models');

var _super_orderline = models.Orderline.prototype;

models.Orderline = models.Orderline.extend({
    set_quantity: function(quantity){

        // Call SUPER method!!
        _super_orderline.set_quantity.apply(this,arguments);

        // =============
        // DO YOUR STUFF
        // =============

    }
});

});
```

BTW, You can find same example in odoo 10...
Check [multiprint.js](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/10.0/addons/pos_restaurant/static/src/js/multiprint.js#L115) file!!

Comment: I am still in confusion, in another example i used `.include` to inherit a function. But in your solution use `.extend`, How? Why?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `module.Orderline.include` instead of `module.include` [[source](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/c2f2bea6c51914b1fadc66af90aac10e00fbeacc/addons/pos_restaurant/static/src/js/multiprint.js#L80-L120)], as `point_of_sale.models` is an [object](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/c2f2bea6c51914b1fadc66af90aac10e00fbeacc/addons/point_of_sale/static/src/js/models.js#L21).

```js
odoo.define('point_of_sale.models_inherit', function (require) {
    "use strict";

    var module = require('point_of_sale.models');
    module.Orderline.include({
        set_quantity: function(quantity) {
            console.log('initialize');
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but now getting this error `message: "module.Orderline.include is not a function"`